# Events not showing fullcalendar in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm trying to display events on `fullcalendar` in Laravel. My code is below.

This is the controller methods:

```
 public function index()
{
    return $this->eventsToArray(EtudiantEvent::all());
}

public function eventsToArray($events){
    $eventArray = [];
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $data = [
            "titre" => $event->title,
            "Debut" => $event->start_date,
            "Fin" => $event->end_date,
            "textColor" =>"white"
        ];
        array_push($eventArray, $data);
    }
    return response()->json($eventArray);
}
```

This is the script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: ['dayGrid', 'interaction'],
          header : {
            left : 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
            center : 'title',
            right : 'dayGridMonth, dayGridWeek, dayGridDay'
          },
          navLinks : true,
          editable :true,
          selectable : true,
          eventLimit : true,
          events : '/etudiantEvent'
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
```

Comment: What is the output of your PHP code? And what are you seeing in the calendar?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post any errors if you are running into any

Comment: Your events must have properties named "start" and "end". You cannot translate those to other languages as you have done. They must have exactly those names, in English.

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much that solved my problem